# Stop Db initialization with EF6 code first

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF6 code first. Below line improves performance as it stops executing many migrations checks and only executes the query in DB

```
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<MyDBContext>());
```

But, if I use the above line when database does not exists, it will throw and exception as this will also prevent from creating the database for the first time. So, to overcome this, I used the below line :

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
```

But, this line still executing those extra migration checking before executing query.

So, is there any way in EF code first so that DB will be creating for the first time if not exist and also, stop executing migration checks for query?

Comment: no, there is no premade initializer that will both create database if it not exists and not checks the Schema for validity, so you'll have to write your own. This is a rather trivial Task though, as you could just check if your DB file exists in the constructor and if not call Database.Create() (override null initializer).

Comment: Yes, custom initializer: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm